# My node app will run on beefy but I am unable to get it to run on foreman or heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, foreman

My node app runs fine when deployed with beefy, however, I keep experiencing errors when trying to deploy on foreman/heroku. Is there something fundamental that beefy is doing which foreman/heroku cannot/does not?

Comment: could you please add more context as to what the error is? or what error messages are showing?

Comment: I get an error reading "TypeError: Cannot call method 'requestQuota' of undefined" in regards to the code 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024*8, function(grantedBytes) {
  window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInit, onError)})' however when I remove the line entirely foreman seems to run then abruptly exits outputting "Killing all processes with signal  null." I'm trying to record output from a webAudio oscillator using the [wave-recorder module](https://github.com/mmckegg/wave-recorder).